# Keep radio playing in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

hi i'm trying to create a simple Online Radio i want to keep radio playing in `bakcground` and i know i should use `Service` but i don't how to use it please help me to make my app radio keep playing in background

this my code :

```
Button b_play ;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

String stream = "http://stream.radio.co/s98f81d47e/listen";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    b_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("Loading");

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(started){
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_play.setText("Play");

            }else{
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("Pause");
            }
        }
    });
}


class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void ,Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        b_play.setEnabled(true);
        b_play.setText("Play");

    }


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(started){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(started){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(prepared){
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Play the music from the foreground service.

**Official Android documentation says**:

> that is a service that the user is actively aware of and is not a
>   candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. A foreground
>   service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is
>   placed under the Ongoing heading. This means that the notification
>   cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed
>   from the foreground.

In your case a **radio** that plays music from a service should be set to run in the foreground, because the user is explicitly aware of its operation. The notification in the status bar might indicate the current song and allow the user to launch an activity to interact with the music player.

Here is an [example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example)

Comment: Then you missed something, try again.